# Handling ember actions from bootstrap addons Notifications component

Tags: ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use [Ember Addons Bootstrap for Ember](https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember), specifically their [Notifications](http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/notifications) component.

I have a new requirement to create an Undo button on the notifications. I can successfully put hbs template code into the message:

```
msg = "Success! <a href='#' {{action 'undo'}}>undo</a>"
Bootstrap.NM.push msg.htmlSafe(), "success"
```

This displays the Undo link nicely, but no matter where I put the action handler within my app, I can't get it to get triggered.

What's the best way to tie the Notifications code into my app so that the undo action can be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't supported.

Not suggesting this, but if you have a hard requirement and you give up on other routes, you will need to accesss Ember outside of the ember application's scope.

```
"Success! <a href='#' onclick='foobar()'>undo</a>"

function foobar(){
  // where App is your Ember app
  // and foo is the controller name, App.FooController
  var controller = App.__container__.lookup('controller:foo');
  controller.send('undo');
}
```

Comment: +1, but I am hesitant to choose this as the answer. Q: any idea why I can pass strings to the method/action, but passing an object like 'this' causes issues...

Comment: to which action? to the undo action?

Comment: this is pretty nasty you'd have to agree @Kingpin2k

Comment: Are you referring to the statement where I already didn't suggest it?  Talking to Ember from outside of Ember requires some sort of global hook, or communication via the container.  Grabbing instances from the container only looks ugly when you write it all out, you could easily write helper methods if you are forced to go down that route.  Additionally using the container ensures proper encapsulation of your app.  If you go the global route, testing becomes more complex etc.